# Is AOP enabled in JBoss AS 7?

Tags: java, jboss5.x, jboss7.x

I was able to deploy a WAR file with AOP enabled in JBoss Application Server 5. I passed the spring-agent jar as the javaagent parameter.

### But I am not able to deploy the war file in JBoss AS 7. Is AOP enabled in AS 7?

EDIT:

[AOP Support in JBOSS 4](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/aop.chapt.html)

So, AOP Support is present in JBoss AS 4, and I was able to make it work in AS 5. 
Application Server 7 is the latest version and one would expect to find some word about it in the AS 7 documentation. I am not able to find anything.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

Read the JBoss Community forum thread on this topic: [JBoss AOP is not part of AS 7](http://community.jboss.org/message/617358)

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything, but JBoss 7 is. There is (currently) no explicit JBoss AOP support in 7.

Comment: Is there any workaround to enable it? Any hints as to how to proceed further?